Is this OEM section in an .inf driver file a bug?
I can't seem to find the driver name. Instead of specifying the name, this .inf seems to specify;
[Manufacturer]
%OEM%=OEM,NTx86,NTamd64
[OEM.NTx86]
%PRINTER1%=INSTALL_SECTION,USBPRINT\HPHP_Color_LaserJet_4596
%PRINTER1%=INSTALL_SECTION,WSDPRINT\HPHP_Color_LaserJet_4596
%PRINTER1%=INSTALL_SECTION,HPHP_Color_LaserJet_4596
%PRINTER1%=INSTALL_SECTION,MF\Color_LaserJet_Pro_M453-4&WSD&IP_PRINT

Is this a bug where some placeholder was not changed to what the driver should be called? If not, how do I obtain the driver name? It's obviously not %PRINTER1%
Automated installation, installers, and semi-manual installation have failed me for this printer on one computer (probably because there's something wrong with the drivers), so I went with manual powershell. I haven't ever had to detangle this weird and wonderful file format, so I wonder if someone could shed some light on this?
All the code/examples just say 'yeah just grab the name from the .inf file'. So, where and how, exactly? I can think of 400,000 ways to grab a 'name' (which honestly can be any valid string) from this 20kB file.

If it works on every other computer then the problem is the one computer it does not work on. The easy option will be to backup the data (just in case) then reinstall Windows on the faulty computer.

Text like %PRINTER1% is processed at installation time and subsituted with whatever the installer needs to put there. There is no bug there in the .inf file.

@Andrew Morton But what if there is no installer executable? You have the option to download 'just the driver'. Then this version of the inf file would be useless to me? (I'd like to not have to deal with the bloatware).

There are other files that go with the .inf file. Windows is the installer. Assuming you downloaded the basic driver package (~10 MB), you should be able to run it to extract the files, then right-click on the .inf file and choose "Install".

I tried that... C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hpshc42a4_x64.inf_amd64_5ab420de31f5b6af\hpshC42A4_x64.inf still contains %PRINTER1%.

The installer doesn't change the .inf file, it "sees" %PRINTER1% and substitutes whatever it needs at the time in memory.

There is a [Strings] or [Strings.0411] section in the INF file which actually tells you what the placeholders are to be replaced by. Just find the values there.
The following sequence of Powershell commands manually adds this printer (after downloading the drivers and installing the .INF);
# Change to match IP address 
$IPAddress="10.0.1.74"

Add-PrinterPort -Name "HP upstairs" -PrinterHostAddress "$IPAddress"

# Lookup and change the folder if the driver ID is different for you.
Add-PrinterDriver -Name "HP Color LaserJet Pro M453-4 PCL-6 (V4)" -InfPath "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hpshc42a4_x64.inf_amd64_5ab420de31f5b6af\hpshC42A4_x64.inf"

Add-Printer -Name "hp_117350" -DriverName "HP Color LaserJet Pro M453-4 PCL-6 (V4)" -PortName "HP upstairs"


